# How can I use the conditional null operator to check for null string?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects, null-conditional-operator

I'm trying to execute the LINQ to objects query as follows:

```
var c1 = allCustomers
    .Where(x => x.CompanyName.Replace("'", "").StartsWith(searchText))
    .ToList();
```

This works fine as long as CompanyName is not null.

So, I thought this seems like the perfect place for the new null conditional operator!  Just change to:

```
var c1 = allCustomers
    .Where(x => x.CompanyName?.Replace("'", "").StartsWith(searchText))
    .ToList();
```

and everything should work!

Instead, I get the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I'm not quite sure how to accomplish what I want here.  How would I use the null conditional in this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a coalesce operator to convert the tri-state to a proper boolean.

```
var c1 = allCustomers
    .Where(x => x.CompanyName?.Replace("'", "").StartsWith(searchText) ?? false)
    .ToList();
```

I call `bool?` a tri-state because it can have three values: `true`, `false` and `null`; therefore, converting `bool?` to `bool` is a narrowing conversion that requires explicit treatment.

Answer (score 1):

you need more question marks!  i think you need null coalescing as well, since `x.CompanyName?.Replace` could now also return null.

```
(x.CompanyName?.Replace("'", "") ?? string.Empty).StartsWith(searchText))
```

the `?? string.empty` forces that to be a non-null string, which now supports `.startswith`

Comment: ack, i put mine on the string instead of the bool. i think mine will work, but the  `?? false` versions are better.

Comment: Yeah, the other 2 will short circuit on the .? and simply return false.

Comment: i interpreted the question tool literally on the "check for null string" part, not on the `bool?' part in the details.

Answer (score 1):

Use `??` operator like:

```
Where(x => x.CompanyName?.Replace("'", "").StartsWith(searchText) ?? false)
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation of why the null-coalescing operator would solve this?