# How to parse complex JSON in C#? Ultimately I want to display the result in DataGridView

Tags: c#, json, parsing

This is my first time parsing complex JSON in C# and I am little confused with parsing JSON structure like this. However, I was able to successfully parse the simple JSON. I am including the JSON and the method I am following here:

```cs
[{
    "L1": null,
    "L2": {
        "Name": "XXX",
        "contact": "xxxxx",
        "address": "XXXX"
    }
},
{
    "L1": {
        "gender": "XXX",
        "contact": "xxxxx",
        "mail_address": "XXXX"
    },
    "L2": null
}]
```

I am using two separate class like shown below:

```cs
public class L2
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string contact{ get; set; }
    public string address{ get; set; }
}

public class L1
{
    public string gender{ get; set; }
    public string contact{ get; set; }
    public string mail_address{ get; set; }
}

public class Root{
     private L1 L1{get;set;}
     private L2 L2{get;set;}

}
```

I am using these lines to parse:

```
 string jsonText = File.ReadAllText("log_test.txt");
 List<Root> data = (List<Root>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(jsonText);
```

When I run it, it runs without any errors but my ultimate goal is to display all the results in a table (or DataGridView). How do I access every properties? In the first object, L1 doesn't have any fields but it does have fields in second object. So how can I do "L1.gender" ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: What is `parser`? Is it a class? If so please [edit] your question to include it

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes Parser was my class. I just changed my question and code little bit. Can you please have a look at it once?

Comment: Isn't that just a dictionary ? `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, ContactClass>>>(json)`

Comment: Are those really name L1 L2, in both List element? Or can we flatern it ?

Comment: In the Root class L1 and L2 are private, those should be public.

Comment: Note that *parsing* is not the same as *deserializing*.

Comment: You can use the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) to access members of a member that might be null, e.g. `root.L1?.gender`. See: [How can I use the conditional null operator to check for null string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36804926/3744182), [Trying to understand ?. (null-conditional) operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38103963/3744182), or [Nullcheck multi level object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43355592/3744182).

Comment: In fact this might be a duplicate of those, agree?  If not, please [edit] your question to clarify where you are stuck.  Maybe you are looking for something like [Winforms DataGridView databind to complex type / nested property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/683796) or [Is it possible to bind complex type properties to a datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121274)?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the root class of the Json.
Use this site https://json2csharp.com/ to create al the classes.
and you will get the following.
This will make sure all fields are mapped.

```
List<Root> myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>myJsonResponse); 
public class L1
{
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string contact { get; set; }
    public string mail_address { get; set; }
}

public class L2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string contact { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public L1 L1 { get; set; }
    public L2 L2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I apologize I missed to mention that I have already included the root class and it is same as you have mentioned. Still I am having the problem. The site that you gave me gave me DeserialedClass of type Root but you have mentioned it as a List. Is it supposed to be a list as I have repeated data?

Comment: Yes, your json is a list so that's why i changed the code from the website to better match your question. @PratikShrestha

Answer (score 0):

Imo L1 and L2 are not properties name. And have variable name.

We can just define a Contact class:

```
public partial class Contact
{
    [JsonProperty("gender", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("contact")]
    public string ContactContact { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("mail_address", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string MailAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("address", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize Like :

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, Contact>>>(input);
// result[0]["L2"] To access L2 values.
```

We can allso latter the whole thing to a `List<KeyPairValue..` :

```
var flatternResult = result.SelectMany(x=>x);
foreach (var contactInformation in flatternResult) {
    Console.Write($"\n\n{contactInformation.Key}: is null? {contactInformation.Value == null}\n");
    Console.WriteLine(""
       +"\n Address         : "+ contactInformation.Value?.Address
       +"\n ContactContact  : "+ contactInformation.Value?.ContactContact
       +"\n Gender          : "+ contactInformation.Value?.Gender
       +"\n MailAddress     : "+ contactInformation.Value?.MailAddress
       +"\n Name            : "+ contactInformation.Value?.Name
    );

}
```

Live demo https://dotnetfiddle.net/9kGUj6

Comment: Did you merge the two separate classes? Also the function Dump didnt work on mine.

Comment: Dump fonction is specific to this online Edi. It's use to dump thing on the screen. I didn't merge any class. I assumed it was just the same . There is no logical difference between the Two. Those looks like contact information. I don't see a domain where I will pair gender with mail and not with name nor adsress. Null and empty value can be ignored at serialization.

Comment: For displaying the Name for example you can do `contactInformation.Value.Name`

Comment: For the L1 L2 thing it's simple. how will you handle L3? Will you recompile all your code just to create a property?

Comment: Thanks for the response once again. So what if I want to get the value result [0] [ "L1"].gender? Its throwing me an exception as there is not properties inside L1 for the first object. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: That's because L1 is null . You will not be able to acces any thing on a null.. The real question is what do you want from null? Do you want them to be new object with no value ? or may you just test if they are null before accessing their properties? Btw i changed the fiddle code you can look at see how i removed the Dump

Comment: Now I am getting your point. My main goal is to get these values and display it on DataGridView or DataTable. Can you please help me with this too? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also, How will I perform LINQ operation in that?

Comment: At this point this is a ping pong game. too many follow up question. are the L1 important do you have to display it ? if L1/L2 was a field of contact what will be it's name? Everything is just a list, pretty sure you can linQ that. SelectMany I used is LinQ.

Comment: @PratikShrestha - *My main goal is to get these values and display it on DataGridView or DataTable. Can you please help me with this too?*, *Also, How will I perform LINQ operation in that?* - The rule on stack overflow is to ask [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735), so you should ask another question.